# Filtering a resource by a field of a related resource

Tags: api, rest

We have these resources:

- Events
- Teams
- Leagues

An event has a team1 and team2 field.

A team has a league field.

A league has a user_id field.

We want to allow users of our API to be able to filter an event by a user.

What's a good uri structure to use?

1) `api/events?userId=<user_id>`

2)  Because user_id field belongs to a league and a league belongs to a team (team1 or team2):

a) `api/events?team1__league__userId=<user_id>`

b) `api/events?team2__league__userId=<user_id>`

c) `api/events?team__league__userId=<user_id>` (will match user_id of team1 or team2)

3) `insert_your_suggestion_here`

Answer (score 1):

The first one `api/events?userId=<user_id>`. Other alternatives violate the [Information Hiding](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?InformationHiding) principle, because you are exposing details about how the data is stored.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is it might conflict with the fields of events. Example: The events resource might also have a user_id field but you want to filter by the list by the user_id of the league. How would you handle that scenario?

Comment: Inherently any league and team would belong to one user, so why not
`api/events?firstTeamId=<team_id>`, and
`api/events?leagueId=<league_id>`? You could also expose the user as an object, like `api/users/<user_id>/events`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to match the user of the league in either team, so
"c) api/events?team__league__userId= (will match user_id of team1 or team2)" would be the way to go.
It's ok to introduce a made up query parameter as you suggest.